# How do you echo a string with every char in PHP?

Tags: php, string, echo

I need to know if there's a way in PHP to echo a string with every char.

For instance

```
/n
```

and the likes.

---

**Edit for clarification**:

When I have a webform and I submit it and I have this text:

```
I am stupid
and I cannot
explain myself
```

The text would be like this:

```
I am stupid /n and I cannot /n explain myself
```

If I use:

```
nl2br
```

I get:

```
I am stupid <br /> and I cannot <br /> explain myself
```

Now I have users that input some messed up texts and I need to clean it and put it inside an array. I would love to be able to print to screen every special char such as /n.

Comment: A couple people have expressed that they do not fully understand your question. Perhaps you could add some more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think he means that instead of seeing a newline when a string contains '\n' he wants to see the '\n' as two characters, a '\' and an 'n'.

json_encode works well for this purpose:

```
echo json_encode("spam\nand eggs");
>> "spam\nand eggs"
```

Comment: but he wants other characters to be escaped. And, I suspect, not only C-style escapes

Comment: Indeed he does.  `addcslashes` is just an option.  `json_encode` will, I believe, return everything OP needs, if this is, in fact, what OP was looking for.

Comment: My answer updated to remove `addcslashes` which works for specific lists of characters that you provide.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I don't know how you managed to understand my question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to add \n to every character and `$string` contains the string you want to edit:

```
$strarray = str_split($string);
$string = "";
foreach($strarray as $char)
{
    $string .= $char."\n";
}
echo $string;
```

After this $string will contain the original $string with a newline added after every character, and will be echoed. For this to be displayed, you'd have to surround it with `<pre>` though.

Comment: $i=0; while isset($string[$i]) echo $string[$i++]."\n"; But it isn't what he asked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think he wants to [break string into chars](http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/how-to-break-a-string-or-word-into-an-array-with-php-t6902.html) and want to print each char in new line. is it ?